# Laravel 5 Behat Mink, cannot locate base_url

Tags: laravel, testing, bdd, behat, mink

I am new to BDD but my issue is that All my test Scenarios failed even though, I can see them working on browser.
So I am guessing Behat must be pointing to a wrong URL which I can't figure out. My behat.yml content is:

```
default:

extensions:
    Laracasts\Behat\ServiceContainer\BehatExtension: ~
    Behat\MinkExtension\ServiceContainer\MinkExtension:
        base_url: http://localhost/omw/public
        default_session: laravel
        laravel: ~
```

What could be the reason why test like

```
Feature: Testing
```

In Order to understand Behat
  As a Developer

Scenario: homepage

```
When  I go to "/"
Then  I should see "hello"
```

should fail?

Comment: I assume `http://localhost/omw/public` displays the word `hello`, right?

Comment: It does on the browser, yes. My other observation is that it worked on my on Laravel installation, still L 5, but not on the newly created one...

Comment: My conclusion at this time is that Laravel 5.1 is not yet compatible with behat/plugin. Hopefully, the plugins will be update. So I reverted back to Laravel 5.0